# Can't import python library 'zipfile'

Tags: python-2.7, zip

Feel like a dunce. I'm trying to interact with a zip file and can't seem to use the zipfile library. Fairly new to python

```
from zipfile import *
#set filename
fpath = '{}_{}_{}.zip'.format(strDate, day, week)

#use zipfile to get info about ftp file
zip = zipfile.Zipfile(fpath, mode='r')
# doesn't matter if I use     
#zip = zipfile.Zipfile(fpath, mode='w')
#or zip = zipfile.Zipfile(fpath, 'wb')
```

I'm getting this error

> zip = zipfile.Zipfile(fpath, mode='r')
>
> NameError: name 'zipfile' is not defined

if I just use import zipfile I get this error:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: with `from zipfile import *`, you have to use `ZipFile` without the prefix. for the other error, I think there's a typo somewhere, it should work (did you call your file `zipfile.py` ? that wouldn't be a good idea)

Comment: If I don't use the prefix I get: NameError: name 'zipfile' is not defined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two ways to fix it:

1) use `from`, and in that case drop the `zipfile` namespace:

```
from zipfile import *
#set filename
fpath = '{}_{}_{}.zip'.format(strDate, day, week)

#use zipfile to get info about ftp file
zip = ZipFile(fpath, mode='r')
```

2) use direct `import`, and in that case use full path like you did:

```
import zipfile
#set filename
fpath = '{}_{}_{}.zip'.format(strDate, day, week)

#use zipfile to get info about ftp file
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(fpath, mode='r')
```

and there's a sneaky typo in your code: `Zipfile` should be `ZipFile` (capital `F`, so I feel slightly bad for answering...

So the lesson learnt is:

- avoid `from x import y` because editors have a harder time to complete words
- with a proper `import zipfile` and an editor which proposes completion, you would never have had this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to zip a file using Python:

```
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile("targetZipFileName.zip",'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zf.write("FileTobeZipped.txt")
zf.close()
```